# When sale price is 0.00 show only regular price

Tags: functions, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, uploads

I run my woocomerce product updates via excel sheet uploads with over 10,000 products. However, with the sale price/promo price column, I have prices of 0.00, 0 and some blank.

I want a situation whereby when a product has a sale price of 0.00 it should only show regular price.

I used to use this function

```
function check_sale_price ($sale_price) {
    if ( empty( $sale_price ) ) {
           return;
    } else {
           return $sale_price;
    }
}
```

However, this isn't working anymore.

Kindly help. Thanks in advance